# Enable set of radio buttons when text box is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my small program I want to enable a set of radio buttons when my password filed's get matched. I'm using PHP to get data from a database and while loop the HTML code to create the radio buttons. below is my script code and HTML codes.

JavaScript:

```
function checkPass() {
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("pWord1"),
        pass2 = document.getElementById("pWord2"),
        role = document.getElementsByName("userRoles"),
        matchColor = "#66cc66",
        noMatchColor = "#ff6666";

    if (pass1.value === pass2.value){
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML ="Passwords match!";
        pass1.style.backgroundColor = matchColor;
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = matchColor;
        role.disabled = false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML ="Passwords do not match!";
        pass1.style.backgroundColor = noMatchColor;
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = noMatchColor;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="userRoles">User Role:</label><br>
<?php while ($row = $getUserRoleQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
  <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="<?php echo $row["urId"]; ?>" disabled><?php echo $row["userRole"]; }?>
</div>
```

Above HTML / PHP code will create something like this,

```
<div id="userRoles">
<label for="userRoles">User Role:</label><br>
<input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="1" disabled>Admin
<input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="2" disabled>Manager
<input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="3" disabled>Team Leader
<input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="4" disabled>User
</div>
```

Problem is my javascript doesn't remove the disable attribute from the radio buttons. Can some one point me down the right path or show me what I'm not doing right.

**UPDATE:** Solved the problem thank's to @JoYthi now my working JavaScript look like this.

```
function checkPass() {
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("pWord1"),
        pass2 = document.getElementById("pWord2"),
        role = document.getElementsByName("userRoles"),
        matchColor = "#66cc66",
        noMatchColor = "#ff6666";

    if (pass1.value === pass2.value){
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML ="Passwords match!";
        pass1.style.backgroundColor = matchColor;
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = matchColor;

        for (var i = 0; i < role.length; i++){
            role[i].disabled = false;
        }

    }else{
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML ="Passwords do not match!";
        pass1.style.backgroundColor = noMatchColor;
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = noMatchColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: add inside the if if (pass1.value === pass2.value){ 
 { ... document.getElementByName("userRoles").disabled = false; .. }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you need `for loop` for disable each radio button.

2) And also you need to enable the disabled property on else part if user password is match it's remove the disabled property . again if user changed in password field and it  doesn't match means while radio button is enabled so in this case you need to disabled it in else part .

```js
$('#pWord1,#pWord2').on('keyup', function () {

    var pass1 = document.getElementById("pWord1"),
        pass2 = document.getElementById("pWord2"),
        role = document.getElementsByName("userRoles"),
        matchColor = "#66cc66",
        noMatchColor = "#ff6666";

    if (pass1.value === pass2.value){
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML ="Passwords match!";
        pass1.style.backgroundColor = matchColor;
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = matchColor;
       for (var i=0;  i < role.length; i++) {
        role[i].disabled = false;
        } 
    }else{
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML ="Passwords do not match!";
        pass1.style.backgroundColor = noMatchColor;
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = noMatchColor;
         for (var i=0;  i < role.length; i++) {
          role[i].disabled = true;
          } 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <input type='text' id='pWord1'>
  <input type='text' id='pWord2'>
      <div id="userRoles">
            <label for="userRoles">User Role:</label><br>
            <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="1" disabled>Admin
            <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="2" disabled>Manager
            <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="3" disabled>Team Leader
            <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="4" disabled>User
        </div>
        <span id="msg"color="red" ></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you your loop worked sometime I'm stupid but learning stuff. Else part I think it wont be used due to all the radio buttons are already disabled until they are enabled by the match command.

Comment: i noticed that before your comment and removed it too . glad to help you @Jack

Answer (score 0):

Here is an sample using JQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#text').change(function(){
            $('.userRoles').removeAttr('disabled');
        });  
        });
    </script>

    <div>
        <input type='text' id='text'>
      <div id="userRoles">
            <label for="userRoles">User Role:</label><br>
            <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="1" disabled>Admin
            <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="2" disabled>Manager
            <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="3" disabled>Team Leader
            <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="4" disabled>User
        </div>
    </div>
```